# iBook G4 hard disk issue - how to repair broken HFS filesystem?

Tags: hard-drive, hfs, ibook

The OS does not boot, it stays in blue blank screen with scrolling bar.

I restarted to single user mode and tried fsck - it said it cannot repair fs.

Restarting with OSX install diskette: it did not show the hard disk in the list of target drives.

Any ideas, how to check if the HD is physically broken?

By pressing D during boot (with install disk inserted)  did not seem to do anything (according to Google, shouldn't it open hardware test?)